# The UserId, Password or Account is invalid Teradata .Net Connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, teradata

The below code throws an error

> The UserId, Password or Account is invalid.

on the code line `adapter.Fill(ds);`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Teradata.Client.Provider;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TdConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new TdConnectionStringBuilder();
        connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "URL";
        connectionStringBuilder.Database = "DB";
        connectionStringBuilder.UserId = "USERNAME";
        connectionStringBuilder.Password = "PASSWORD";
        connectionStringBuilder.AuthenticationMechanism = "LDAP";


        TdConnection cn = new TdConnection();

        cn.ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        cn.Open();

        TdCommand cmd = new TdCommand("EXEC MACRO", cn);
        TdDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        TdDataAdapter adapter = new TdDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, cn.ConnectionString);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

       // myLabel.Text= ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["event_id"].ToString();

        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();

    }
}
```

However, the below code works perfectly fine and returns value as expected.

```
TdConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new TdConnectionStringBuilder();
            connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "URL";
            connectionStringBuilder.Database = "DB";
            connectionStringBuilder.UserId = "USERNAME";
            connectionStringBuilder.Password = "PASSWORD";
            connectionStringBuilder.AuthenticationMechanism = "LDAP";

            TdConnection cn = new TdConnection();
        cn.ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
        cn.Open();

        TdCommand cmd = new TdCommand("Show table DB.TABLE1", cn);
        String customers = (String)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        MeanTime.Text = customers;
        cmd.Dispose();
        cn.Close();
```

The user ID, Password, Datasource etc are all same yet it fails on 1st code but runs properly on 2nd.

Comment: No experience with teradata - this may not be correct. But what if you try "cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure" under your cmd declaration? It doesn't seem to be the cause of the error, but I've had issues when I don't declare it - might be some weird result being returned. Only takes a sec, worth a shot.. If that's even an option on a TdCommand.

Comment: Tried adding the suggestion. Still facing the same error.

Comment: Yeah sorry man, I've seen strange things with sqlcommands, thought itd be worth a shot.

Comment: Does that proc hit a different table or db that has different permissions?

Comment: @Aaron Same DB, same table, Same level of permissions.

Comment: check for parameter  LOGMECH=LDAP and check table dbc.logonoff to see if locked. Best I can do, gotta wait on the experts from here on out. Best of luck: https://community.teradata.com/t5/Connectivity/Error-8017-The-UserId-Password-or-Account-is-invalid/m-p/30513

Answer (score 0):

When calling procs and macros you can use the `TDCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`.

UPDATE: Upon further reading [here](https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/15.11/help/Teradata.Client.Provider~Teradata.Client.Provider.TdCommand~CommandType.html) it looks like you can include the `CALL` when using the Stored Procedure commandtype. The proper Commandtype for a Macro execution is `System.Data.CommandType.Text` and you probably need the `EXEC`

For reference, with parameter binding and a procedure, here's a working example below. Some small tweaks would need to be made (as mentioned above) for a macro execution.

```
//create a new td connection
TdConnection cn = new TdConnection();

//Build the connection string
TdConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new TdConnectionStringBuilder();
connectionStringBuilder.DataSource = "serveraddress";
connectionStringBuilder.Database = "defaultdatabase";
connectionStringBuilder.UserId = "username";
connectionStringBuilder.Password = "password";
connectionStringBuilder.AuthenticationMechanism = "LDAP";
connectionStringBuilder.CommandTimeout = 120; 

//Open the connection
cn.ConnectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ConnectionString;
cn.Open();

// Initialize TdCommand from the tdconnection
TdCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();

//CommandText is set to Stored Procedure name, in this case,
//.NET Data Provider will generate the CALL statement.
cmd.CommandText = "yourdatabasename.yourprocname";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

// Create Input Parameter required by this procedure
TdParameter InParm1 = cmd.CreateParameter();
InParm1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
InParm1.DbType = DbType.String;
InParm1.Size = 20;
InParm1.Value = "yourparamvalue";

//and bind it
cmd.Parameters.Add(InParm1);

//------------OPTION 1 CATCHING AN OUTPUT PARAMETER---------------------
    //If you are catching an output parameter from a proc then create here:
    // Create Output Parameter.
    TdParameter OutParm = cmd.CreateParameter();
    OutParm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    OutParm.ParameterName = "myOutputParam";
    OutParm.DbType = DbType.String;
    OutParm.Size = 200;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(OutParm);

    // Run it up
    cmd.ExecuteReader()

    //if this is returning a single value you can grab it now:
    myOutput = OutParm.Value.ToString();


//------------OPTION 2 CATCHING A RECORDSET-----------------------------

    //list based on class set in seperate model
    List<myClass> l_myclass = new List<myClass>();

    //run it up and catch into a TDDataRead
    using (TdDataReader r = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (r.HasRows)
        {
            //Loop the result set and catch the values in the list
            while (r.Read())
            {
                //"myclass" class defined in a seperate model
                //Obviously you could do whatever you want here, but
                //creating a list on a class where the column1-column4 is defined makes short work of this. 
                //Then you can dump the whole l_myclass as json back to the client if you want.
                myClass i = new myClass();
                i.column1 = (!r.IsDBNull(0)) ? r.GetString(0) : string.Empty;
                i.column2 = (!r.IsDBNull(1)) ? r.GetString(1) : string.Empty;
                i.column3 = (!r.IsDBNull(2)) ? r.GetString(2) : string.Empty;
                i.column4 = (!r.IsDBNull(3)) ? r.GetString(3) : string.Empty;
                l_myClass.Add(i);
            }
        }
    }

    //Dump the list out as json (for example)
    return Json(l_myClass, System.Web.Mvc.JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I've only, personally, used this on procedures, but [the documentation](http://community.teradata.com/t5/Connectivity/NET-Executing-macro-and-statement-cache/td-p/28014) I've read suggests that this is the correct route for macros as well.